# magento 2: debug to addtocart simple product for one qty in stock

Tags: addtocart, quoteitem, magento2.4.0

I am trying to figure out the flow add to cart item.

**Note: before add to cart my cart is empty**

I have a simple product and it has one qty and product `inStock` is yes, it does not go `prepare` function in following path `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Processor.php`  because I put `die()` function in `prepare` function for testing ,it did not call `die()` function and product added to cart successfully, but how ? and then clear my shopping cart and when I change the qty from 1 to 2 for same product and save it then I try to add to cart it goes to prepare function in following file `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Processor.php`

but how differently works based on qty ?

Please help me on this
I am using magento2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you properly, but you say that if you have a product with qty = 1 and you add it to cart then magento does not go into `prepare()` function of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Processor.php` and when you have qty = 2 it goes to `prepare()`? If yes, than it's not normal, I can't give you a solution because on my instance every time I add a product to a cart (no matter how many qty it has in stock) it always launches the `prepare()` function.

It is hard to tell what is happening, maybe some custom module is messing with the logic, but the best way to debug it would be to use xdebug and set some breakpoints in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addProduct()` and in the controller action that handles add to cart (not sure if you use some custom module for this or not). If you did not use xdebug yet, I highly recommend it, it will spare you a lot of time in a situations like this.